# Can elementary OS run on HP ENVY 13 (2017 models)

Tags: system-installation, hp

Hey buying a new laptop and looking at HP ENVY 13 as it is a very good laptop with reasonable pricing. The specs that I think will affect if elementary can run is as below:

Intel 8th Gen i7-8550U
nVidia MX 150
CPU fan that will turn on only when it reaches a certain temperature.
USB type-C ports
microSD slot
Broadcomm WiFi

With the above in mind, has anyone gotten elementary to run on a HP ENVY 13 or anything equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

What does not work: MicroSD card slot, Two front-facing speakers.

What works with issues: USB-C with a USB hub plugged in (the ethernet is wonky, then again might not be the laptop's fault).

What should you do after installing eOS on this: Install TLP and powertop. Else your power and temperature will suffer.

Comment: Is this info from your own personal experience with elementary OS on an HP Envy 13, or from second-hand experience you heard / read somewhere? It's just useful to clarify.

Comment: First hand experience